# Azure Data lake Gen2 Kafka sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am looking for Azure Data lake Gen2 Kafka sink connector. Everywhere it redirects me to confluent website.[Link for confluent](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-azure-data-lake-gen2-storage?_ga=2.126480395.769523973.1648956061-1948744128.1632831502&_gac=1.156509769.1648727012.CjwKCAjwopWSBhB6EiwAjxmqDaM2Xj7YhoY3fOiL8v_vayNvitN1tAptqUS9ILDgJfBAoglOo6d7axoC1_IQAvD_BwE). However when I am clicking to view source code option on the page the link seems to be broken. [Source Code link](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-azure-blob-storage/kafka-connect-azure-data-lake-gen2-storage.). I am new to Kafka connect. Is there any other Github or articles which I can refer to Azure blob storage sink Kafka connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a private repo. You won't find the source code for it.

The only reference you should need is the [configuration properties](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-azure-data-lake-gen2-sink/current/configuration_options.html#connect-azure-data-lake-gen2-storage-configuration-options)
from the first link.

Comment: Is there any other Github or articles which I can refer for some open source  Azure blob storage sink Kafka connect?

Comment: I commonly suggest using something like Apache Nifi for getting around Confluent licensing